# Sum of the digits?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let, $\ n$  be the smallest positive number,
 such that:

the number, 
$\ S=8^n5^{600}$ has 604 digits

What is the sum of the digits?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what made you to think that this is important for you?

Comment: Actually I was having problem with **5^600**, I was wondering the length of that number....I should have thought in **10 ^600** terms. Rest of the portion will become easy to think then. Thanks again to all of you & stack exchange for your support.

Comment: you have not responded to any of the answers... what would then be the use of thinking of helping you (from the context of users who answered this)... you should have been more responsible....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: It looked to me like you were OP.  Sorry.

Comment: @RossMillikan : It is alright sir,there is nothing to say sorry ... you have helped me a lot.. I like this question....

Answer (score 8):

If $n=200$ then $S=8^{200}\cdot 5^{600} = 2^{600}\cdot 5^{600} = 10^{600}$ that has $601$ digits.

so if $n=204$ you have $S=8^4\cdot 10^{600} =4096\cdot 10^{600}$. It has $604$ digits and the sum is $4+9+6=19$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  how many digits does $10^{600}$ have?  How does this help?

Comment: I am not at all familiar with this kind of questions but your hint made me to try something.... $10^{600}$ has $601$ digits... but how do i go further. please suggest something..

Comment: Do you see how to get $10^{600}$?  Now you have to multiply it by something to get three more.  All you have to play with is $8^n$

Comment: yes... I could see that $10^=100$ has $3$ digits, $10^3=1000$ has $4$ digits in similar manner $10^{600} $ would have $601$ digits...

Comment: That is correct.  A particular $n$ will give you $8^n5^{600}=10^{600}$  Now what happens if you increase $n$ by $1$?  By $2$? What are the new products?

Comment: I need $8^n=2^{600}$ then i would have $8^n 5^{600}=2^{600}5^{600}=10^{600}$... So i need $8^n=2^{600}$ i.e., $2^{3n}=2^{600}$ this implies $n=200$...

Comment: Now, i will let $n=201$ this will mean i will multiply $8^{200}5^{600}$ with $8$... this will not increase the number of digits as i am multiplying by something less than $10$.. Now, i will let $n=202$ this will mean i will multiply $8^{200}5^{600}$ with $8^2$... this will make number of digits increase only by $1$ digits as i am multiplying by something less than $100$..Now,  i will let $n=203$ this will mean i will multiply $8^{200}5^{600}$ with $8^3$...

Comment: this will make number of digits increase only by $2$ digits as i am multiplying by something less than $1000$.. Now,  i will let $n=203$ this will mean i will multiply $8^{200}5^{600}$ with $8^3$... this will make number of digits increase only by $3$ digits as i am multiplying by something less than $10000$.. originally i had $601$ digits and now after multiplying with $8^3$ i have $3$ more digits on the whole i have $604$ digits and so i am done... I have to choose minimum $n$ as $204$.. I hope i have understood this correctly... :)

Comment: Yes, the number of digits increases by one less than $8^n$.  You need an extra three digits, so need $8^n$ to have four digits.  As $8^4=2^{12}=4096$, that is what you need.  So $8^{604}5^{600}$ has $604$ digits.  The first are $4096$ and the rest are all zero.  The sum is then $19$

Answer (score 0):

The condition that $8^n\cdot 5^{600}$ has $604$ digits can be written
$$
\log_{10}(8^n\cdot 5^{600})\ge 603
$$
or
$$
3n\log_{10}2+600(1-\log_{10}2)\ge 603,
$$
that is,
$$
3n\log_{10}2\ge3+600\log_{10}2
$$
or
$$
n\ge\frac{1}{\log_{10}2}+200=\log_{2}10+200,
$$
so the minimum $n$ is $204$, because $3<\log_{2}10<4$.

Thus $S=8^{4}\cdot10^{200}$.